# Why is jQuery attr returning undefined for 'id' but not 'href'?

Tags: jquery, undefined, attr

I am trying to get the id from li elements using jQuery attr('id'), but it is returning undefined even though it does return what appears to be the correct values for attr('href'). I'm stumped.  Here's [a link](https://codepen.io/pcdavis/pen/zPvBwx?editors=1111) to my Codepen

```
  <ul id="sortList">
  <li id="one"><a href='#'>Ratings</a></li>
  <li id="2"><a href=#>Reviews</a></li>
  <li id="3"><a href=#>Type</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h2 id="anchorInfo">hello</h2>
  <h2 id="clickInfo">hello</h2>


  $('#sortList li').click( function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  let whatHref = $(event.target).attr('href');
  let whatId = $(event.target).attr('id');
  document.getElementById('anchorInfo').innerHTML = whatHref;
  document.getElementById('clickInfo').innerHTML = whatId;
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
  $(event.target).attr('id');
```

try

```
  $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `event.target` is the link, and that doesn't have an `id`. You need to get it from the parent:

```
$(event.target).parent().attr('id')
```

Comment: Just use `this` instead of  `event.target`. It will be the `<li>`

Comment: @charlietfl Ah, because the `click` handler is on the `li`... you're right.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to target each of the individual elements using the jQuery .each() function. You will then be able to target the clicked elements by using the 'this' selector. Finally to target the anchor you need to find the child element of the clicked li by using the jQuery .find() function. You should then be good to go by friend! [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEyajx?editors=1111)

Reviewed and tested jQuery code:

```
$('#sortList li').each(function(){
  $(this).click(  function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let whatHref = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    let whatId = $(this).attr('id');
    document.getElementById('anchorInfo').innerHTML   = whatHref;
    document.getElementById('clickInfo').innerHTML   = whatId;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery each function. Then, instead of using *this* reference, you should use *item* as parameter from which you may do things treating it as *HTMLLIElement*.

Answer (score -1):

To use `.attr` you need pass a `data-attribute` like `data-id="something"`. Try use `.prop()`

```
  <ul id="sortList">
  <li id="one"><a href='#'>Ratings</a></li>
  <li id="2"><a href=#>Reviews</a></li>
  <li id="3"><a href=#>Type</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h2 id="anchorInfo">hello</h2>
  <h2 id="clickInfo">hello</h2>


  $('#sortList li').click( function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  let whatHref = $(event.target).prop('href');
  let whatId = $(event.target).prop('id');
  document.getElementById('anchorInfo').innerHTML = whatHref;
  document.getElementById('clickInfo').innerHTML = whatId;
  })
```